# Conditional check inside nested array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After a few pipeline stages, I came up with following sample result which is one document. If the `videos.views.userId` contains `10`, I need to indicate `videos.isWatched = true` else `false`. We can use `$unwind`, check the condition, then `group` it.

This is sample output, The original document contains a lot of field, so I just like to do with less code unless I need to `unwind` Is there any way to do **without** `unwind("videos")`?

```
[
    {
        "_id":"someId",
        "videos":[
            {
                "_id":"1",
                "name":"A",
                "views":[
                    {
                        "userId":10,
                        "group":"X"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id":"2",
                "name":"B",
                "views":[
                    {
                        "userId":20,
                        "group":"Y"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Assessment":[
            {
                "_id":"22",
                "title": "Hello world"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected result

```
[
    {
        "_id":"someId",
        "videos":[
            {
                _id:"1",
                name:"A",
                views:[
                    {
                        userId:10,
                        group:"X"
                    }
                ],
                "isWatched":true
            },
            {
                _id:"2",
                name:"B",
                views:[
                    {
                        userId:20,
                        group:"Y"
                    }
                ],
                "isWatched":false
            }
        ],
        "Assessment":[
            {
                _id:"22",
                title: "Hello world"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) along with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to add a new field to an existing array. [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) can be used to determine whether there's any `userId` equal to `10`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            videos: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$videos",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$this",
                            { 
                                isWatched: {
                                    $anyElementTrue: {
                                        $map: { input: "$$this.views", in: { $eq: [ "$$this.userId", 10 ] } }
                                    }
                                }  
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Srj_SiVSQXQ)